# Why does this union type not require all attributes?

Tags: typescript

We were debugging a test, where we wanted to mock a function call that has an argument that satisfies `AB`, but we were surprised when we were allowed to pass an object that only had partial values for `B`. Why does `const a` satisfy type `ABC` despite not having `d`?

```js
type A = {a: number};
type B = {b: number, c: number, d: number};
type AB = A & B;
type ABC = A | AB;

const a: ABC = {a: 1, c: 2}; // passes, despite not having `d`
const az: ABC = {a: 1, c: 2, z: 3}; // fails because `z` is neither in A nor B
```

Comment: Unions in TS are inclusive, and excess property checking only happens in specific circumstances.  `ABC` allows `A` without caring about excess properties mentioned in `AB` for that reason. [ms/TS#14094](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094) was the (eventually declined) suggestion to have an "exclusive union" operator, and [ms/TS#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863) is the (still open) suggestion to perform excess property checks on all unions as opposed to just discriminated unions.  See the linked questions and answers for more information.

Comment: @jcalz why does `az` fail then? my first thought was `a` passes because it satisfies `A` and the excess property is ignored (and it's a coincidence that it's something in `B`), but then `az` fails with `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'z' does not exist in type 'ABC'.`

Comment: i think i found the answer: because typescript has a special case where it _does_ check for excess properties, and that check is distinct from the satisfaction logic: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks

Comment: `z` is not mentioned in either `A` or `AB` so it’s considered an excess property.  But `c` is mentioned in `AB` so it’s not. I don’t think anyone likes this latter behavior, hence the ms/TS#20863 feature request linked above.